# Нумерация объектов

Tags: cocoa, objective-c

Есть объект "polygonObject". Каждый раз по окончанию рисования полигона и созданию нового, объект пересоздается заново. Старый затирается. Нужно чтото вроде "polygonObjectN" или "polygonObject[i]". Есть какойто выход?

Comment: Пробовали добавлять полигоны в массив для доступа по индексу или объекту Polygon добавить @property (nonatomic) NSInteger tag; ?

Comment: Еще не пробовал. Спасибо за ответ. Познания в objective-c у меня еще скудноваты =)

Comment: Вам нужно хранить старый объект? Пользуйтесь массивами.